# How can I minimize a phone call programmatically?

Tags: android, phone-call

I have an App where a "Help Call" can be invoked. And I want that the call is running in background when sombody had accept the call. So is there a way to minimize the phone call and meanwhile get back to the app?

Comment: You can try to relaunch the activity when you detect the phone call start

Comment: Thanks for reply. You brought me on an idea, thanks.

Comment: @silvia_aut Can you please post your solution if you have one? Basically I want to make a phone call, hide the In Call Screen and bring up my own task so the user can see my app and be in the call at the same time

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
                break;
            }
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {
                try {
                    //THIS WILL SIMULATE A HOME BUTTON PRESS
                    //Effectively Minimizing the In Call Screen
                    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    activity.startActivity(startMain);

                    //Now that you are home, and your In Call Screen is minimized
                    //move back to your application
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did someone try this? I am not sure if it will minimize call screen and bring the app back to foreground.

Comment: It does, but there is also a check you should keep in mind for pre and post Android 11. The bring to front solution works on 11 and later, but this works in 10 and below, I have a solution in working condition. Used by a company I did this for, I will see if I can get it to you

Comment: Hey @Pierre, this solution is very helpful but how I can move back to my application programmatically??

Comment: @piyushpk You can store the open Activity's TaskId in a static variable. In your activity, override `onWindowFocusChanged` and call `mystaticvarTaskId = getTaskId();`. Then when you want to show your activity again, get an instance of `ActivityManager` and call `am.moveTaskToFront(mystaticvarTaskId, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);`